# How to get the list of friends in facebook for logged in user using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the following code to get the list of friends for the given secret key , how to get the list of friends for logged in userid (irrespective of appid, and secret id).

```
 <?php

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId' => 'appId',
       'secret' => 'secretKey',
       'cookie' => true,
           ));

    $app_id = "appId";
    $app_secret = "secretKey";
    $my_url = "myurl";


    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       error_log($e);
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting with this code?

Comment: I am not getting any error, i am getting friends for the specific account ( I mean the appId, and secret key). I just want to know how to get the list of friends for logged in user, I mean generic method that will accept the user credential and return back the friends, or any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data from graph api, you need to assiciate with an app(i.e. you must use app id and app secret).

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<?php

    $app_id = "appId";
    $app_secret = "secretKey";
    $my_url = "myurl";

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId' => $app_id ,
       'secret' => $app_secret ,
       'cookie' => true,
           ));
```

Comment: in your code $facebook contain some app_id, so if i say like $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');, I will be getting list of friends for given app_Id, i want to get the friends irrespective of app_id, using logged in details i have to get the friends.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete Tested Code

```
<?php
require '/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '738188999529253',
  'secret' => '744a01c3630802882850754898bebb32',
));

$app_id =   '738188999529253';
$app_secret = '744a01c3630802882850754898bebb32';

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    print "</pre>";


} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_friends,read_stream, export_stream'));
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login:<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>                                
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: brother i have tired u r code its working well localhost when i move the code server its showing blank page  brother ? please help me out this issues ?